# Simplifying a summation over Möbius and the divisor functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

Let $s,\nu$ be two complex variables. We have the double infinite sum: 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\sigma(j)}{n(js+\nu)(nsj+n\nu-1)}$$
Is there a way to simplify the summation, maybe to an ordinary single sum.

Comment: Please show some of your efforts at least.

Comment: this formula is a result of a long series of simplifications of a given integral. Alas, this is the furthest i could go! hence, the question.